# Creating a search tab which searches a text file in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, search, manifest, searchview

Im trying to create an android app with two tabs. One tab will search for data then display it in a listview, when you select one item there it will redirect you to another tab showing the full item (more like a dictionary,showing a list of words and when you click a word it will show you the full meaning of a word in another tab). I'm having problems implementing the search part. I followed the steps on the official android site: http://developer.android.com/training/search/setup.html.

but Im getting errors when I try to change the Manifest file,here is my Manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.swm.empire.psalmsongbook" >

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".SplashScreen"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".SearchResultsActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name">

        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"


        <meta-data
            android:name="android.app.searchable"
            android:resource="@xml/searchable" />

            />

    </application>

</manifest>
```

My Tab2.java is the one which handles the search page, here is my Tab2.java file:

```
package com.swm.empire.psalmsongbook;

import android.app.SearchManager;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.SearchView;

/**
 * Created by VinceGee on 7/22/2015.

public class Tab2 extends Fragment {
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_2, container, false);
    return v;
}*/


public class Tab2{
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.options_menu, menu);

    return true;
}

// Associate searchable configuration with the SearchView
SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager)    getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);

SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.search).getActionView();
searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));

return true;
}



}
```

I created a DatabaseTable.java as the article said here it is:

`package com.swm.empire.psalmsongbook;`

```
import android.app.SearchManager;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.ComponentName;
import android.content.ContentResolver;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.content.IntentSender;
import android.content.ServiceConnection;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.pm.ApplicationInfo;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.content.res.AssetManager;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.DatabaseErrorHandler;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQueryBuilder;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Looper;
import android.os.UserHandle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Display;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

/**
 * Created by VinceGee on 7/23/2015.
 */

public class DatabaseTable extends Context {
    private static final String TAG = "DictionaryDatabase";

//The columns we'll include in the dictionary table
public static final String COL_WORD = "SONG";
public static final String COL_DEFINITION = "LYRIC";

private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "SONGBOOK";
private static final String FTS_VIRTUAL_TABLE = "FTS";
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

private final DatabaseOpenHelper mDatabaseOpenHelper;

public DatabaseTable(Context context) {
    mDatabaseOpenHelper = new DatabaseOpenHelper(context);
}

@Override
public AssetManager getAssets() {
    return null;
}

@Override
public Resources getResources() {
    return null;
}

@Override
public PackageManager getPackageManager() {
    return null;
}

@Override
public ContentResolver getContentResolver() {
    return null;
}

@Override
public Looper getMainLooper() {
    return null;
}

@Override
public Context getApplicationContext() {
    return null;
}

@Override
public void setTheme(int resid) {

}

@Override
public Resources.Theme getTheme() {
    return null;
}

@Override
public ClassLoader getClassLoader() {
    return null;
}

@Override
public String getPackageName() {
    return null;
}

@Override
public ApplicationInfo getApplicationInfo() {
    return null;
}

@Override
public String getPackageResourcePath() {
    return null;
}

@Override
public String getPackageCodePath() {
    return null;
}

@Override
public SharedPreferences getSharedPreferences(String name, int mode) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public FileInputStream openFileInput(String name) throws FileNotFoundException {
    return null;
}

@Override
public FileOutputStream openFileOutput(String name, int mode) throws FileNotFoundException {
    return null;
}

@Override
public boolean deleteFile(String name) {
    return false;
}

@Override
public File getFileStreamPath(String name) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public File getFilesDir() {
    return null;
}

@Override
public File getNoBackupFilesDir() {
    return null;
}

@Nullable
@Override
public File getExternalFilesDir(String type) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public File[] getExternalFilesDirs(String type) {
    return new File[0];
}

@Override
public File getObbDir() {
    return null;
}

@Override
public File[] getObbDirs() {
    return new File[0];
}

@Override
public File getCacheDir() {
    return null;
}

@Override
public File getCodeCacheDir() {
    return null;
}

@Nullable
@Override
public File getExternalCacheDir() {
    return null;
}

@Override
public File[] getExternalCacheDirs() {
    return new File[0];
}

@Override
public File[] getExternalMediaDirs() {
    return new File[0];
}

@Override
public String[] fileList() {
    return new String[0];
}

@Override
public File getDir(String name, int mode) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public SQLiteDatabase openOrCreateDatabase(String name, int mode, SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public SQLiteDatabase openOrCreateDatabase(String name, int mode, SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory, DatabaseErrorHandler errorHandler) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public boolean deleteDatabase(String name) {
    return false;
}

@Override
public File getDatabasePath(String name) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public String[] databaseList() {
    return new String[0];
}

@Override
public Drawable getWallpaper() {
    return null;
}

@Override
public Drawable peekWallpaper() {
    return null;
}

@Override
public int getWallpaperDesiredMinimumWidth() {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public int getWallpaperDesiredMinimumHeight() {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public void setWallpaper(Bitmap bitmap) throws IOException {

}

@Override
public void setWallpaper(InputStream data) throws IOException {

}

@Override
public void clearWallpaper() throws IOException {

}

@Override
public void startActivity(Intent intent) {

}

@Override
public void startActivity(Intent intent, Bundle options) {

}

@Override
public void startActivities(Intent[] intents) {

}

@Override
public void startActivities(Intent[] intents, Bundle options) {

}

@Override
public void startIntentSender(IntentSender intent, Intent fillInIntent, int flagsMask, int flagsValues, int extraFlags) throws IntentSender.SendIntentException {

}

@Override
public void startIntentSender(IntentSender intent, Intent fillInIntent, int flagsMask, int flagsValues, int extraFlags, Bundle options) throws IntentSender.SendIntentException {

}

@Override
public void sendBroadcast(Intent intent) {

}

@Override
public void sendBroadcast(Intent intent, String receiverPermission) {

}

@Override
public void sendOrderedBroadcast(Intent intent, String receiverPermission) {

}

@Override
public void sendOrderedBroadcast(Intent intent, String receiverPermission, BroadcastReceiver resultReceiver, Handler scheduler, int initialCode, String initialData, Bundle initialExtras) {

}

@Override
public void sendBroadcastAsUser(Intent intent, UserHandle user) {

}

@Override
public void sendBroadcastAsUser(Intent intent, UserHandle user, String receiverPermission) {

}

@Override
public void sendOrderedBroadcastAsUser(Intent intent, UserHandle user, String receiverPermission, BroadcastReceiver resultReceiver, Handler scheduler, int initialCode, String initialData, Bundle initialExtras) {

}

@Override
public void sendStickyBroadcast(Intent intent) {

}

@Override
public void sendStickyOrderedBroadcast(Intent intent, BroadcastReceiver resultReceiver, Handler scheduler, int initialCode, String initialData, Bundle initialExtras) {

}

@Override
public void removeStickyBroadcast(Intent intent) {

}

@Override
public void sendStickyBroadcastAsUser(Intent intent, UserHandle user) {

}

@Override
public void sendStickyOrderedBroadcastAsUser(Intent intent, UserHandle user, BroadcastReceiver resultReceiver, Handler scheduler, int initialCode, String initialData, Bundle initialExtras) {

}

@Override
public void removeStickyBroadcastAsUser(Intent intent, UserHandle user) {

}

@Nullable
@Override
public Intent registerReceiver(BroadcastReceiver receiver, IntentFilter filter) {
    return null;
}

@Nullable
@Override
public Intent registerReceiver(BroadcastReceiver receiver, IntentFilter filter, String broadcastPermission, Handler scheduler) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public void unregisterReceiver(BroadcastReceiver receiver) {

}

@Nullable
@Override
public ComponentName startService(Intent service) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public boolean stopService(Intent service) {
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean bindService(Intent service, ServiceConnection conn, int flags) {
    return false;
}

@Override
public void unbindService(ServiceConnection conn) {

}

@Override
public boolean startInstrumentation(ComponentName className, String profileFile, Bundle arguments) {
    return false;
}

@Override
public Object getSystemService(String name) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public int checkPermission(String permission, int pid, int uid) {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public int checkCallingPermission(String permission) {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public int checkCallingOrSelfPermission(String permission) {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public void enforcePermission(String permission, int pid, int uid, String message) {

}

@Override
public void enforceCallingPermission(String permission, String message) {

}

@Override
public void enforceCallingOrSelfPermission(String permission, String message) {

}

@Override
public void grantUriPermission(String toPackage, Uri uri, int modeFlags) {

}

@Override
public void revokeUriPermission(Uri uri, int modeFlags) {

}

@Override
public int checkUriPermission(Uri uri, int pid, int uid, int modeFlags) {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public int checkCallingUriPermission(Uri uri, int modeFlags) {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public int checkCallingOrSelfUriPermission(Uri uri, int modeFlags) {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public int checkUriPermission(Uri uri, String readPermission, String writePermission, int pid, int uid, int modeFlags) {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public void enforceUriPermission(Uri uri, int pid, int uid, int modeFlags, String message) {

}

@Override
public void enforceCallingUriPermission(Uri uri, int modeFlags, String message) {

}

@Override
public void enforceCallingOrSelfUriPermission(Uri uri, int modeFlags, String message) {

}

@Override
public void enforceUriPermission(Uri uri, String readPermission, String writePermission, int pid, int uid, int modeFlags, String message) {

}

@Override
public Context createPackageContext(String packageName, int flags) throws PackageManager.NameNotFoundException {
    return null;
}

@Override
public Context createConfigurationContext(Configuration overrideConfiguration) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public Context createDisplayContext(Display display) {
    return null;
}

private static class DatabaseOpenHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private final Context mHelperContext;
    private SQLiteDatabase mDatabase;

    private static final String FTS_TABLE_CREATE =
            "CREATE VIRTUAL TABLE " + FTS_VIRTUAL_TABLE +
                    " USING fts3 (" +
                    COL_WORD + ", " +
                    COL_DEFINITION + ")";

    DatabaseOpenHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        mHelperContext = context;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        mDatabase = db;
        mDatabase.execSQL(FTS_TABLE_CREATE);
        loadSongbook();
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        Log.w(TAG, "Upgrading database from version " + oldVersion + " to "
                + newVersion + ", which will destroy all old data");
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + FTS_VIRTUAL_TABLE);
        onCreate(db);
    }

    private void loadSongbook() {
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    loadWords();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    throw new RuntimeException(e);
                }
            }
        }).start();
    }

    private void loadWords() throws IOException {
        final Resources resources = mHelperContext.getResources();
        InputStream inputStream = resources.openRawResource(R.raw.songs);
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));

        try {
            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                String[] strings = TextUtils.split(line, "-");
                if (strings.length < 2) continue;
                long id = addWord(strings[0].trim(), strings[1].trim());
                if (id < 0) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "unable to add word: " + strings[0].trim());
                }
            }
        } finally {
            reader.close();
        }
    }

    public long addWord(String song, String lyric) {
        ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
        initialValues.put(COL_WORD, song);
        initialValues.put(COL_DEFINITION, lyric);

        return mDatabase.insert(FTS_VIRTUAL_TABLE, null, initialValues);
    }
}
public Cursor getWordMatches(String query, String[] columns) {
    String selection = COL_WORD + " MATCH ?";
    String[] selectionArgs = new String[] {query+"*"};

    return query(selection, selectionArgs, columns);
}

private Cursor query(String selection, String[] selectionArgs, String[] columns) {
    SQLiteQueryBuilder builder = new SQLiteQueryBuilder();
    builder.setTables(FTS_VIRTUAL_TABLE);

    Cursor cursor = builder.query(mDatabaseOpenHelper.getReadableDatabase(),
            columns, selection, selectionArgs, null, null, null);

    if (cursor == null) {
        return null;
    } else if (!cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        cursor.close();
        return null;
    }
    return cursor;
}

DatabaseTable db = new DatabaseTable(this);

private void handleIntent(Intent intent) {

    if (Intent.ACTION_SEARCH.equals(intent.getAction())) {
        String query = intent.getStringExtra(SearchManager.QUERY);
        Cursor c = db.getWordMatches(query, null);
        //process Cursor and display results
    }
}
}
```

There is bunch of code Android studio added to fix this portion:

```
DatabaseTable db = new DatabaseTable(this);

private void handleIntent(Intent intent) {

    if (Intent.ACTION_SEARCH.equals(intent.getAction())) {
        String query = intent.getStringExtra(SearchManager.QUERY);
        Cursor c = db.getWordMatches(query, null);
        //process Cursor and display results
    }
}
}
```

So please correct me where I'm going wrong, or give a better method, I have searched around but other methods that i found provide searching from code output and not from a text file.